# How to include a local library in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

While I was creating an `Angular` application I wanted to build a library where I can put components which can be useful even in other projects. In order to create the library I've made another `Angular` workspace where I've generated the library project and used the application project generated automatically within the workspace to show individual components.

```sh
ng new my-components-library
cd my-components-library
ng generate library components-library
```

Now I have a library with working components which pass the unit tests and works properly in the attached application project but I need them in my project's workspace. I tried to include the library on this way.

Inside my project workspace

```
npm install ../my-components-library/projects/components-library
```

the command run properly and I get a reference to the library into the host project's `package.json` but when I have to include modules from the external library in a project's module using `import {myModule} from 'components-library'` I get an error because Angular can't find the module.

Comment: You should install your local library with the `npm link` command instead of the `npm install` command. Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

Comment: cant we set the path in tsconfig.json in paths section like "paths": {
      "components-library": [
        "../my-components-library/projects/components-library"
      ]
}

Comment: Hi, you need to build your library create a package and install the package to your main module this is how library works, if you need further detail let me know will provide you

Answer (score 14):

##### You can either use `npm link`, which creates a symlink in your host apps node_modules directory.

- Run `npm link` in the local library
- Run `npm link @local-library-name` in the host application
- But make sure you make the following changes on your host applications `angular.json` file. If you are using less angular 11 or lower, then add `"preserveSymlinks": true` else `sourceMap` with `scripts`, `styles`, `vendor` as true

```
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true, // angular 11 or less
      }
    },
```

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "sourceMap": {     // angular 12 or more
              "scripts": true,
              "styles": true,
              "vendor": true
            },
```

##### You can package the library into tar using `npm pack`.

- Run `npm pack` in your library
- Run `npm i your-library-path.tgz` in your host application
- Or you can update the package.json with new dependency of the host application and run `npm i`

```
"your-library-name": "file:your-library-path.tgz",
```

Comment: "sourceMap" option does not exist for Angular 14.

Comment: `preserveSymlinks` works fine on Angular 13 too for me.

Answer (score 1):

Need to register in angular.json

`"scripts": ["src/assets/scripts/yourComponentLibrary.js"]`

In you component where you want to use the library, need to declare as a const above @Component({...

`declare const YourComponentLibraryName: any;`