# NPM link - Application cannot find linked library's dependencies [ANGULAR]

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-link

I am developing an application and a library used in said application. I need to update the library, however, when I use NPM link the application says that the library I have imported does not have the dependencies required. This is a deployed library and does work when not using NPM link and instead using the deployed version. Is there an extra step I am missing to include the dependencies in the link process, or is there an extra command I need to run?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue. The way I resolved it was by adding `"preserveSymlinks": true` in the `angular.json` file.

The layout should be:

```
"build": {
    "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
    }
},
```

Please note, this is only a solution for versions of angular 11 or less

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58374143/how-to-include-a-local-library-in-angular) offers a solution for versions greater than 11

Comment: fix link "answer" please